# Spark read HDFS slow after run several hours

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

We have a spark streaming application, for each interval it will read a hive table and do some aggregation, usually it's very fast and can finish in 20 seconds. However after run several hours, one executor will be very slow, while other executor is fast as normal, I check the slow server: disk, network has no problem and there is other executors of other application on same server, they are all good.

The CPU usage of slow executor is 100%, and I get threaddump of slow executor, it is reading HDFS, stack below. The data size reading is 128M, it should be done in several seconds, but in this slow executor it takes 90+ seconds.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**2017-06-15 15:04:04**

```
"Executor task launch worker-172" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fb308001000 nid=0x3966 runnable [0x00007fb338a4c000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder.decodeArrayLoop(UTF_8.java:211)
at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder.decodeLoop(UTF_8.java:354)
at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:561)
at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:783)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:405)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:382)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.toString(Text.java:280)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveInspectors$class.unwrap(HiveInspectors.scala:322)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$.unwrap(TableReader.scala:315)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(TableReader.scala:401)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(TableReader.scala:401)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$$anonfun$fillObject$2.apply(TableReader.scala:416)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$$anonfun$fillObject$2.apply(TableReader.scala:408)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:389)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.processInputs(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:511)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.<init>(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:686)
```

**2017-06-15 15:04:07**

```
"Executor task launch worker-172" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fb308001000 nid=0x3966 runnable [0x00007fb338a4c000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.misc.Unsafe.getByte(Native Method)
at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.get(DirectByteBuffer.java:249)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.get(ByteBuffer.java:673)
at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.get(DirectByteBuffer.java:279)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.get(ByteBuffer.java:694)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.DataChecksum.verifyChunkedSums(DataChecksum.java:304)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.readNextPacket(RemoteBlockReader2.java:203)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.read(RemoteBlockReader2.java:138)
- locked <0x00000007bed42868> (a org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream$ByteArrayStrategy.doRead(DFSInputStream.java:683)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readBuffer(DFSInputStream.java:739)
- locked <0x00000007bed42808> (a org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:796)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:837)
- locked <0x00000007bed42808> (a org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream)
at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:180)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:209)
- locked <0x00000007bed41c58> (a org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:47)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:249)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:211)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
at scala.collection.Iterator$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at scala.collection.Iterator$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at scala.collection.Iterator$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:388)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.processInputs(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:511)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.<init>(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:686)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$anonfun$doExecute$1$anonfun$2.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:95)
```